# Glut without access to g++

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I have been playing around with GLUT for a while. So far I have been using a mac and compiled my code with g++

When I began school this year I got a new pc. Unfortunetly I am not admin on the pc and I do not have access to g++ in command prompt.

Are there any other way i can compile some c++ GLUT code like this:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glut.h> 

void display (void) {  
    glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);  
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); 
    glLoadIdentity();  

    glFlush();
}  

int main (int argc, char **argv) {  
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_SINGLE);
    glutInitWindowSize (500, 500);  
    glutInitWindowPosition (100, 100);  
    glutCreateWindow ("Your first OpenGL Window");  

    glutDisplayFunc(display);  

    glutMainLoop();  
}
```

Comment: As with any standard C++ code, it should compile using any other popular compiler, such as VC++ or clang.  Also I can't imagine there not being a way to tweak permissions so you can run g++; and if you're in school for programming, not having permissions to run a compiler sounds like a bad thing.

Comment: No I'm not in a school for programming, just want to program a bit when i have time

Comment: if it is your PC then get yourself admin rights

Comment: @chunnoo: Chances are good that there is gcc installed, even if g++ is missing. The code example above is actually C, not C++ (the parameter definition of `display` is a telltale sign, `…(void)` in C means "function receiving no parameters", while `…()` in C means "function accepting an arbitrary number of parameters but not using them")

Comment: Back in 2007, I had a 'portable' copy of (the windows version of) DevCpp on a flash-drive. I'd imagine that you could get a portable version of either Code::Blocks (with minGW) or DevCpp with minGW. If your "pc" is actually a Mac, I've no idea. You can however, get programs that will allow the creation of portable copies of software. It takes a snap-shot of your system, then you install the software, finally it snapshots the pc again. It determines the added settings/files before wrapping them up neatly into a single 'run-anywhere' exe. (See free equivalents to VmWare thinApp)